# How can I build this recursive method in rails/ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

I'm using a form object pattern in rails, and am generating a data map that consists of nested form objects that I want to commit to the DB.

**For example, I have something like this:**

- ProductFormObject

  - FeatureFormObject1

    - KeyFormObject (ex: Color)
    - ValueFormObject (ex: Red)
  - FeatureFormObject2

    - KeyFormObject (ex: Size)
    - ValueFormObject (ex: Large)

So what I would like to do is recursively validate this data, but I need to start from the bottom up.

In other words, a product without features is invalid, so before I can validate the product I need to validate the features. A feature without a key/value pair (ex: color = red) is invalid. So I need to first validated the key and value form objects.

I figure I can set the state of each form object as having been validated or not. But I'm really not sure how to get this to work from the bottom-up.

I don't really have any code that would be worth sharing, as I'm in the process of building this out now. Pseudo-code could help for now too, and I'll post the final results once I get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things - this doesn't need to be recursive or bottom up.

On ProductFormObject you could have something like

```
def valid?
   feature_form_objects.any? && feature_form_objects.all?(&:valid?)
end
```

To say that there must be at least one child object and they must all be valid.

And then the `valid?` method on FeatureFormObject just needs to verify that both its key and value are valid? (Possibly first checking that they are not nil - depend on how you construct things this may not be possible). You might also need to check that the combination of key and value are valid.

```
def valid?
  key_form_object.valid? && value_form_object.valid?
end
```

Comment: This is great! One small issue though is.. how do I collect the errors at the root form object? If I do it recursively I can add each nested error to the root's error collection. Any ideas?

Comment: You could follow a very similar approach but instead of using && to combine booleans you'd be using + or collect to combine arrays of errors

Comment: so from `#valid?` would you return true/false or a collection? If you're thinking a collection, that would be a bit unexpected.